# Meteor: Creating a collections: Reference Error when debug in chrome console

Tags: node.js, meteor

I follow a tutorial with `Meteor` I try to create a collection, both for client and server. Here is my code:

```
var lists = new Meteor.Collection("Lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

As tutorial I have read, when run on server, if I open chrome console and type `lists` I will receive `Meteor.Collection`. But when I tried on my machine, I received error:

> Reference error. lists is not define

Have I done something wrong? Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Comment: FYI, `Mongo.Collection` is the new `Meteor.Collection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can put all your collections inside the `/lib/collection.js` route (for better practices).

So with that we ensure that meteor loads first the collections, and they will be available on both **client/server**.

you should remove Autopublish/insecure package, to avoid meteor sends all the collections when load and to control who can or not **insert/remove/update** on the collections.

```
meteor remove autopublish
meteor remove insecure.
```

So a simple collection will look like this.

```
    //lib/collection.js
    Example = new Mongo.Collection("Example") //we create collection global
    if(Meteor.isClient) {
     Meteor.subscribe('Example') //we subscribe both after meteor loads client and server folders
    }
```

now on `/server/collections.js`

```
Meteor.publish('Example', function(){
          return Example.find(); //here you can control whatever you want to send to the client, you can change the return to just return Example.find({}, {fields: {stuff: 1}});
        });
```

// Here we control the security of the collections.

```
 Example.allow({
      insert: function(userId, doc) { 
        if(Meteor.userId()){
         return true; //if the user is connected he can insert
     } else{
    return false// not connected no insert
   }
 },
    update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) { //other validation },
    remove: function(userId, doc) { //other validation },
});
```

Just to try to explain a little more deep the Collection here on meteor, hope it help you GL

Answer (score 1):

I think you have autopulish/autosubscribe turned off. Try

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('lists');
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.publish('lists',function(){
        return Lists.find();
    });
}
```

For your naming, I'd also recommend you reverse the way you're capitalizing your collections. So instead it would be

```
var Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");
```

And finally, look at https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-boilerplate for your directory structure so you don't have to do the if meteor.is stuff anymore.

*Edit*

Full code should look like:

```
var Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('lists');
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.publish('lists',function(){
        return Lists.find();
    });
}
```

Comment: can you take care again between "Lists" and "lists" please. Because after I type above code and reverse `Lists` to `lists` I still get the same error result. thanks :)

Comment: I updated my response to have full code. However, pay attention to what you're doing. Copying and pasting isn't a good learning strategy. Look at what meteor is subscribing to, is it the variable you created or the collection you made? What is it publishing? The collection or the variable?

Answer (score 1):

All of your script source files are [wrapped in a function closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860890/why-does-meteor-0-6-0-wrap-everything-into-function) as part of the build process. In order for your collection to be visible outside of that file (or in your case - attached to the `window` object) you will need to declare it as a global variable:

```
Lists = new Meteor.Collection('lists');
```

Note the lack of `var`. As @thatgibbyguy pointed out, the accepted pattern is to capitalize collection variables, and camelcase collection names.

Comment: ah. nice :) I understand your point. I can fix my problem now :)