# Meteor + autoform example requested

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In the [autoform docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform), there are many snippets of examples, but I cannot get any of them to work. Principally because autoform, meteor, and finally JS are new to me.

However, I am good at adapting examples, but couldn't find any simple examples. [This is one](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#example) I struggles with. Can I get a working full example of a simple autoform (or quickform) using collections?

1. Assume I have aldeed:autoform and aldeed:collection2 installed.
2. Let's say my files are divided up into

   - both/testform.js
   - server/testform.js
   - client/testform.js
   - client/testform.js?
3. And let's say I'm using a template called "testTemplate" and a collection called "testCollection"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: when you try to make it work, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will try to make it simply.

First create the project and remove the `autopublish and insecure` packages

Second on the `/server/testform.js` put this.

```
TestCollection.allow({
  insert:function(){return true;},
  remove:function(){return true;},
  update:function(){return true;},
})
```

and the [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) function

```
Meteor.publish("TestCollection", function () {
  return TestCollection.find();
});
```

More about [allow](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow)/[deny](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deny) rules

Instead of `/both/testform.js`, put the collection declaration in `/lib/testform.js` as per Meteor best practice to make sure it is evaluated first.

```
TestCollection = new Mongo.Collection("TestCollection");
```

and the [subscription](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/dataandsecurity).

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
     Meteor.subscribe('TestCollection')
}
```

now on `/client/testform.html`

put this.

```
<template name="testForm">
  {{> quickForm collection="TestCollection" id="insertTestForm" type="insert"}} 
</template>
```

now on `/client/testform.js` put the schema

```
TestCollection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({ //take this from docs.
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    max: 200
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    label: "Author"
  },
  copies: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Number of copies",
    min: 0
  },
  lastCheckedOut: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Last date this book was checked out",
    optional: true
  },
  summary: {
    type: String,
    label: "Brief summary",
    optional: true,
    max: 1000
  }
}));
```

**NOTE**

If you are new on Meteor/Javascript don't jump into complex packages likes this.

run this and see how they work.

```
meteor create --example todos 
meteor create --example local market
```

or take a look into [the meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/install)

For **Javascript** this tutorial/guide help me a lot [How to Learn Javascript properly](http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/)

Comment: The console reports "Uncaught ReferenceError: TestCollection is not defined" in client/testform.js. If I add 

    TestCollection = new Mongo.Collection("TestCollection");

to the top of that file I get another error "Uncaught Error: There is already a collection named 'TestCollection'" in collection.js (but the form renders). And if I comment out the TestCollection line in both/testform.js I get a meteor error "ReferenceError: TestCollection is not defined". Suggestions?

Comment: Okay, problem solved and suggested edits above. Better if the collection definition is done in lib/collections.js as per your answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137912/meteor-creating-a-collections-reference-error-when-debug-in-chrome-console). Loading order and all that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did get it working with a bit of experimentation. I'm not brand new having worked with a few other complicated packages, but new enough that the idiosyncrasies of meteor and its packages can confound me. I appreciate your help and experience with the package.

Comment: can you approve the edits I made to your answer. As it stands currently, it is not working.

Comment: Not sure if you get notification when I suggest edits to your answer, but lemme try again.